# There is a small space below the img

Tags: html, css, materialize

There is always a 6 pixels space below the image. I am using materialize instead of bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="no-padding">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/testing.datahub.io/static/img/logo-cube03.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

Also link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q00269ag/)

My code is very simple, even I clean all of the other things.

When I inspect on `div class="no-padding"` it shows 486 pixels and when I inspect on the `img` it shows 480 pixels.

I want to remove the 6 pixels space.

Comment: row class shows 20px margin bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: block;` to the image is one fix.

See also : [What is the gap or extra space below image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Thanks. That works.